Problem with switching language with using useHead in Nuxt 3 application
I have a component in Nuxt 3 application that shows a embeded form.
<template>
  <div :class="['form-embed', classList]" :style="background ? { backgroundColor: background } : ''">
    <div :class="wrapper">
      <h4>{{ props.data.form_embed_title }}</h4>
      <p class="text">{{ props.data.form_embed_text }}</p>
      <div class="form-container">
        <div :id="props.data.form_embed_form_id" :lang="locale"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script setup>
const { locale } = useI18n();

const props = defineProps({
  data: { type: Object, default: () => {} },
});
const { classList, background, wrapper } = useUseStyling(props.data, 'form_embed', false);

const scriptSrc = ref(props.data.form_embed_source_id);
const scriptRef = ref(null);
useHead({
  script: [
    {
      id: props.data.form_embed_script_id,
      src: scriptSrc.value + '?t=' + Date.now(),
      defer: 'defer',
      ref: scriptRef,
    },
  ],
});

watch(locale, () => {
  if (scriptRef.value) {
    scriptRef.value.src = props.data.form_embed_source_id + '?t=' + Date.now();
    // Adding a query parameter can help bypass browser caching
  }
});
</script>

Script is IIFE function. My question is how can i on language change re-run that IIFE function again.
The problem is that the script is same for all the languages, what changes is locale in this bit of a code:
<div :id="props.data.form_embed_form_id" :lang="locale"></div>

but i need to rerun that IIFE function in script that is loaded in head again to form to be shown in different language when language is changed.
Any ideas?
Thanks!
